# Give sudo access to celery workers

Tags: python, celery

I have a python program that needs to executed like this;

```
$ sudo python my_awesome_program.py
```

Now I want to run thousands of instances of this program using celery, of course with different parameters. The Problem is that while celery tries to execute my program it fails and the reason is that it doesn't have `sudo` access.

How can I give my celery workers the power of `sudo` to run this program ?
I already tried to give sudo access to my user. Changed celery service owner etc.

May be a stupid question, but I am lost.

P.S
**task.py**

```
from celery import Celery
import os
import socket
import struct
import select
import time
import logging
# Global variables
broker = "redis://%s:%s" % ("127.0.0.1", '6379')
app = Celery('process_ips', broker=broker)
logging.basicConfig(filename="/var/log/celery_ping.log", level=logging.INFO)
# From /usr/include/linux/icmp.h; your milage may vary.
ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8  # Seems to be the same on Solaris.


def checksum(source_string):
    """
    I'm not too confident that this is right but testing seems
    to suggest that it gives the same answers as in_cksum in ping.c
    """
    sum = 0
    countTo = (len(source_string) / 2) * 2
    count = 0
    while count < countTo:
        thisVal = ord(source_string[count + 1]) * \
            256 + ord(source_string[count])
        sum = sum + thisVal
        sum = sum & 0xffffffff  # Necessary?
        count = count + 2

    if countTo < len(source_string):
        sum = sum + ord(source_string[len(source_string) - 1])
        sum = sum & 0xffffffff  # Necessary?

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff)
    sum = sum + (sum >> 16)
    answer = ~sum
    answer = answer & 0xffff

    # Swap bytes. Bugger me if I know why.
    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)

    return answer


def receive_one_ping(my_socket, ID, timeout):
    """
    receive the ping from the socket.
    """
    timeLeft = timeout
    while True:
        startedSelect = time.time()
        whatReady = select.select([my_socket], [], [], timeLeft)
        howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
        if whatReady[0] == []:  # Timeout
            return

        timeReceived = time.time()
        recPacket, addr = my_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        icmpHeader = recPacket[20:28]
        type, code, checksum, packetID, sequence = struct.unpack(
            "bbHHh", icmpHeader
        )
        if packetID == ID:
            bytesInDouble = struct.calcsize("d")
            timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28:28 + bytesInDouble])[0]
            return timeReceived - timeSent

        timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
        if timeLeft <= 0:
            return


def send_one_ping(my_socket, dest_addr, ID):
    """
    Send one ping to the given >dest_addr<.
    """
    dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(dest_addr)

    # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)
    my_checksum = 0

    # Make a dummy heder with a 0 checksum.
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, my_checksum, ID, 1)
    bytesInDouble = struct.calcsize("d")
    data = (192 - bytesInDouble) * "Q"
    data = struct.pack("d", time.time()) + data

    # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
    my_checksum = checksum(header + data)

    # Now that we have the right checksum, we put that in. It's just easier
    # to make up a new header than to stuff it into the dummy.
    header = struct.pack(
        "bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, socket.htons(my_checksum), ID, 1
    )
    packet = header + data
    my_socket.sendto(packet, (dest_addr, 1))  # Don't know about the 1


def do_one(dest_addr, timeout):
    """
    Returns either the delay (in seconds) or none on timeout.
    """
    logging.info('Called do_one Line 105')
    icmp = socket.getprotobyname("icmp")
    try:
        my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)
    except socket.error as xxx_todo_changeme:
        (errno, msg) = xxx_todo_changeme.args
        if errno == 1:
            # Operation not permitted
            msg = msg + (
                " - Note that ICMP messages can only be sent from processes"
                " running as root."
            )
            raise socket.error(msg)
        raise  # raise the original error

    my_ID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF

    send_one_ping(my_socket, dest_addr, my_ID)
    delay = receive_one_ping(my_socket, my_ID, timeout)

    my_socket.close()
    return delay


def verbose_ping(dest_addr, timeout=1, count=2):
    """
    Send >count< ping to >dest_addr< with the given >timeout< and display
    the result.
    """
    logging.info('Messing with : %s' % dest_addr)
    try:
        for i in xrange(count):
            logging.info('line 136')
            try:
                delay = do_one(dest_addr, timeout)
                logging.info('line 139' + str(delay))
            except socket.gaierror as e:
                break
            logging.info('line 142'+str(delay))
            if delay is None:
                pass
            else:
                delay = delay * 1000
                logging.info('This HO is UP : %s' % dest_addr)
                return dest_addr
    except:
        logging.info('Error in : %s' % dest_addr)


@app.task()
def process_ips(items):
    logging.info('This is Items:----: %s' % items)
    up_one = verbose_ping(items)
    if up_one is not None:
        logging.info('This one is UP: %s' % up_one)
```

**my_awesome_program.py**

```
from task import process_ips

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, 256):
        for j in range(1, 256):
            ip = "192.168.%s.%s" % (str(i), str(j))
            jobs = process_ips.delay(ip)
```

**/etc/defaults/celeryd**

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples).
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/home/jarvis/Development/venv/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"
# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="task"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/jarvis/Development/pythonScrap/nmap_sub"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8 --loglevel=DEBUG"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="jarvis"
CELERYD_GROUP="jarvis"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your CELERYD_USER param in settings.

Have a look here: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html

If you're using supervisor, then in your supervisor conf of celery, you'd need to do this:

```
user=<user-you-want>
```

Also, under [Example Configuration](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-configuration) section, it's explicitly said to not run your workers as privileged users.

Comment: My CELERYD_USER is already sudo user. with no password sudo access.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the `How can I give my celery workers the power to run this program. ` part of your question then? What command exactly did you run to run your celery workers?

Comment: @Nagri: Does the user `jarvis` also own the dir specified by `CELERYD_CHDIR` ?

Comment: But what exactly are the errors you're encountering? You haven't shown any errors happening in your logs or whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81509/discussion-between-nagri-and-bad-keypoints).